# Tabs with Clickpane and Optionboxes

Tags: graphics, dynamic

I want to display a clickable graph using `ClickPane` (on tab one) while behind it are several tabls with lists of items and three options (clickboxes?) next to each (so that the user can change the default allocation of one of three values to each item). Is the best framework in which to do this a `Manipulate` command? What are the corresponding commands for the tabs and the boxes?

Comment: Is this related?  [5576](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5576/question-about-making-tabview-remember-what-tab-to-open)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pursuant to jjc385's comment, the ideal answer is

`DynamicModule[{tab = 2},
 TabView[{
   "Variables" ->
    TabView[{"A" -> TableForm@{{"a=", SetterBar[Dynamic[a], Range@3]},
         {"b=", SetterBar[Dynamic[b], {0 -> "zero", 1, 2}]},
         {"c=", SetterBar[Dynamic[c], {0, .5, 1}]}}
      , "B" -> "Nothing here."}]
   ,
   "Graph" ->
    Dynamic@Plot[Sin[a x + b] + c,
     {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
   }, Dynamic[tab]]
 ]`

which is a little different than the prior code which produced

[image].

Now, the user can change several variables and the display only switches to the graph when the user tabs to it. Thanks!